# How to use interface members in expression

Tags: c#, interface, lambda, expression

I've been struggling a bit with this tiny problem - and I'm quite sure there's an "easy" solution.

I have a generic nHibernate base-repository class with the following method:

```
public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    using (var session = SessionProvider.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

However - I'm trying to control my model by using some very simple interfaces. I have an interface - ISetDeleted:

```
public interface ISetDeleted
{
    bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

In my GetAll()-method I would like to check it the current type implements this interface - and if it does, only return the entities that are not marked as deleted:

```
public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    using (var session = SessionProvider.OpenSession())
    {
        if (typeof(T) is ISetDeleted)
        {
            // Only retrieve entities that are not marked as deleted
            // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
        }
        return session.Query<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

I know I could just retrieve all the entities and loop through these - but I would prefer a cleaner approach - e.g. an expression that implements the check (if possible).

It would be very much appreciated if someone could help me out with this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First

```
typeof(T) is ISetDeleted
```

will only return true if the type parameter **is** ISetDeleted, not if it **implements** the interface.  You probably want

```
if (typeof(ISetDeleted).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

Second, I think you want

```
return session.Query<T>().Where(x => !((ISetDeleted)x).IsDeleted).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq (namespace System.Linq):

```
public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    using (var session = SessionProvider.OpenSession())
    {
        if (typeof(ISetDeleted).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return session.Query<T>().Where(o => !(ISetDeleted) o).Deleted).ToList();
        }
        else 
        {
            return session.Query<T>().ToList(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost had it right then (missing parenthesis around the entire cast) :)
Thank you so much - you guys rock! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can write it like this, it will be easier to extend in future and also allow you to add additional constraints:

```
public IList<T> GetAll()
{
    using (var session = SessionProvider.OpenSession())
    {
        var query = session.Query<T>();

        if (typeof(ISetDeleted).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => !(ISetDeleted)x).Deleted);
        }

        return query.ToList(); 
    }
}
```

which should work provided that session.Query returns an IQueryable